# SonarQube is getting stopped after running for some time

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Earlier I was able to run SonarQube without any problem. But recently after executing ./sonar.sh start script a SonarQube.pid file is being generated and until the time the file is present. Sonar is up but after few secs the file is getting deleted thus making Sonar going down.

I couldn't understand why the problem is occurring suddenly now. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: On the sonar server, check the log file and see what it has. The location would be: c:\program files\sonarqube7.2\logs

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah4110 for providing the location of the logs through which I was able to understand the issue. There was a lock on the folder which Sonar was trying to access after unlocking it. It is working fine

Comment: If that helped, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

On the SonarQube server, check the log files and identify the root cause. If it was installed to the default directory in C:, The location of the log files would be : C:\Program files\sonarqube7.2\logs